# Book about two friends on galactic adventure, who inherit a starship (one has big, spiky blue hair)

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship

I rediscovered this 3-book series a couple years ago, then forgot it again. Pretty sure from before the '90s.

Two guys adventuring amongst the planets; I think one inherited a starship with ancient secrets. On the covers, one guy always has a big, spiky hair, swept back, blue or purple. On one cover, the two are looking over a railing, on another cover they're riding alien mounts. In one story, the antagonist is a huge augmented Native American mercenary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the [*Alacrity Fitzhugh*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?2756) novels by Brian Daley.

Leaning over a railing is [*Jinx on a Terran Inheritance*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5100), the second book of the trilogy; the heroes mounted on riding animals is [*Fall of the White Ship Avatar*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5101), the last book.

[image: Cover of "Jinx on a Terran Inheritance" showing Fitzhugh with blue hair hanging over a railing] [image: Cover of "Fall of the White Ship Avatar" showing Fitzhugh and Floyt on riding beasts]

Comment: Yup, that's it.  I'm going to write it down this time.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to add, the first of the trilogy is [Requiem for a Ruler of Worlds](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?27864),